# Get feature by ID in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a `VectorLayer` layer with a feature collection in GeoJSON. The GeoJSON format is as following:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "totalFeatures": "unknown",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "ES.RRTN.CP.1010001",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                570389.865,
                                4722149.567
                            ],
                            [
                                570391.945,
                                4722149.769
                            ],
                            [
                                570394.939,
                                4722150.04
                            ],
                            [
                                570395.084,
                                4722144.205
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "validTo": {
                    "simpleContent": null
                },
                "validFrom": {
                    "simpleContent": null
                },
                "inspireId": {
                    "Identifier": {
                        "localId": "1010001",
                        "namespace": "ES.RRTN.CP"
                    }
                },
                "label": "1",
                "nationalCadastralReference": "1010001",
                "areaValue": 101.2779,
                "beginLifespanVersion": {
                    "simpleContent": null
                }
            }
        }
    ]
 }
```

I know the feature `id=1010001`, so I can identify a feature by its `id`, `localid` and `nationalCadastralReference`.

> Is there a way to get the `Feature` object from the
>   `VectorLayer`/`VectorSource`/`Map` with one of this parameters?

Comment: `source.getFeatureById('ES.RRTN.CP.1010001')`

Comment: I would say that the only way is to loop through features with `forEachFeature` method of vector source (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#forEachFeature) and check for desired value of desired property.

Comment: @Mike, you overlooked that desired search key is not feature ID but value of some property.

Comment: Thanks @TomazicM, but `source.getFeatureById` also returns the desired feature via ID so I will keep the code simple and use that.

Comment: @Mike please answer for marking as solution

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question, since you do not mention feature ID as one of the desired search properties.

Comment: @TomazicM sorry if I explained myself badly, but the id is included in the parameters mentioned so operations with it are allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution given in the comments finally was:

> `source.getFeatureById('ES.RRTN.CP.1010001')`